# Kubernetes: How to sort by complex keys (eg, node-role.kubernetes.io/general)?

Tags: kubernetes

Sorting by simple keys is straightforward and easy. Both of these work just fine.

```
kubectl get nodes --sort-by=.metadata.name -o wide
kubectl get nodes --sort-by=.metadata.labels.affinity -o wide
```

I'm trying to now sort by complex keys such as .metadata.labels."clm.status" or, more importantly, .metadata.labels."kubernetes.io/roles".

Functionally speaking, I am able to sort by the kubernetes.io/roles using a different way, ie, sort plus other linux commands, so plzzzzz don't give me non-k8s alternatives. I just want to see how to sort using native k8s *get command* with these complex keys.

I tried many permutations, including but not limited to:

```
$ kubectl get nodes --sort-by=.metadata.labels.kubernetes.io.roles -o wide
No resources found

$ kubectl get nodes --sort-by=.metadata.labels.'kubernetes.io.roles' -o wide
No resources found

$ kubectl get nodes --sort-by=.metadata.labels.'kubernetes.io/roles' -o wide
No resources found

$ kubectl get nodes --sort-by=.metadata.labels."kubernetes.io/roles" -o wide
No resources found
```

Comment: For the record, the quotes in your last two examples don't matter; this is a basic shell syntax issue: they are interpreted *by the shell*, so in both cases `kubectl` sees only `--sort-by=.metadata.labels.kubernetes.io/roles`. If you want quoting that's visible to `kubectl`, you'll need to double quote (`--sort-by='.metadata.labels."kubernetes.io/roles"'`).

Comment: @larsks, true. I had already tried `get nodes  --sort-by='.metadata.labels."kubernetes.io/roles"'  -o wide` . Thank you for pointing it out though. I should've mentioned it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the solution is to escape the dots in your label with `\`, so for example:

```
kubectl get nodes \
  --sort=by=.metadata.labels.kubernetes\\.io/roles
```

Or if you prefer, use single quotes on the outside to avoid having to escape the escape character:

```
kubectl get nodes \
  --sort-by='.metadata.labels.kubernetes\.io/roles`
```